# MacBook won't detect displays unless I "detect displays" manually from System Prferences

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, displayport, dvi

My MacBook drives my external DVI monitor (over mini display port, using Apple's adapter) just fine, but it fails to detect changes in the display configuration and doesn't react accordingly unless I manually "detect displays" in System Preferences. It fails to detect both a display being plugged in, AND being unplugged. Anybody know how to troubleshoot/fix this?

I have already:

- Reset NVRAM (fun fact: PRAM is only in PowerPC Macs, in Intel Macs
  it's called [Non-volatile random-access memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_random-access_memory))
- Reset SMC
- Cleaned the Mini-Display Port connector (male and female end).

**Edit:** this set up had been working well for over 2 years and randomly started exhibiting this behaviour ***recently***.

Comment: 1) What is the model of the external DVI monitor? 2) What is the configuration that works, what configuration change(s) isn't detectable?

Comment: It's an LG Flatron W2343T if that mattered lol.

Comment: And it works fine (in terms of display output contents), but my macbook just fails to adapt between the single monitor and dual monitor configurations. It seems to not "notice" the plugging in and unplugging of the monitor.

Comment: Your question suggest you've already done what's recommended in http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1573. I asked the two questions because I was unsure if you've checked http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_site.kbase.search.searchresults_suggested.search&product=&q=supported%20display%20configurations%20MacBook

Comment: I should have mentioned that this set up has been working for over 2 years and randomly started exhibiting this behaviour recently.

Comment: That doesn't sound good.  I encountered similar problem with my MBP and it turned out heat (from running the GPU often with Aperture and FCP) damaged the motherboard. Hope that's not the case with you. Expensive to repair and hard to source replacement motherboard.

Comment: Idk, it seems like it's too random of an issue to constitute a hardware issue. Considering neither the internal nor external display show any sign of artifacting. Frame rates, resolution, colour depth, etc. are all perfectly normal.

Comment: Have you experimented by switching with another display cable to see if the cable or the connector is pooched?

Comment: you guys aren't carefully reading my question… the display works 100% fine apart from requiring manual use of the "detect displays" button